# How to add table to custom post type as custom field in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I have tried Tablepress, wp_table_reloaded plugins. I feel that it will be really complicated for naive user to add table by adding shortcode to each custom post's content also there are so many custom posts in the websiste. Actually I want that table should be added to each custom post type as we add custom fields to each custom post type,then simply adding value to each field. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `add_meta_box` function:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

**Here's the code I used in a recent project, I believe you should be able to adapt the meta box to add a table.**

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'create_meta_boxes' );

function create_meta_boxes() {
  add_meta_box( 'author_info', 'Auteur info', 'author_info_meta_box', 'portfolio', 'normal');
}

function author_info_meta_box( $object, $box ) { ?>
  <p>
    <label for="auteur-meta">Auteur</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="auteur-meta" id="auteur-meta" style="width:100%;" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'Auteur', true ), 1 ); ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="auteur-quote-meta">Quote auteur</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="auteur-quote-meta" id="auteur-quote-meta" style="width:100%;" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'Auteur Quote', true ), 1 ); ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="auteurBioMeta">Biografie auteur</label><br />
    <?php $settings = array(
      'media_buttons' => false,
      'textarea_rows' => 6
    ); ?>
    <?php wp_editor( wp_specialchars( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'Auteur Biografie', true ), 1 ), 'auteurBioMeta' , $settings); ?>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="order-mail-meta">E-mail voor bestellingen</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="order-mail-meta" id="order-mail-meta" style="width:100%;" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'Order Mail', true ), 1 ); ?>" />
  </p>
<?php }

//Insert values on save
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post', 10, 2 );
function save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return $post_id;

  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Auteur', stripslashes( $_POST['auteur-meta'] ) );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Auteur Biografie', stripslashes( $_POST['auteurBioMeta'] ) );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Auteur Quote', stripslashes( $_POST['auteur-quote-meta'] ) );
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'Order Mail', stripslashes( $_POST['order-mail-meta'] ) );
}
```